# Flexicious MultiSelectComboBox Popup Text color

Tags: flexicious

I have a `MultiSelectComboBox` in an `ExtendedAdvancedDataGrid` to filter a column, and when I click on it, the text in the popup box (a list of check boxes) is light grey on a white background.  I tried changing the style using `popUpStyleName`, but nothing changes.

Any idea what could override this style?

Answer (score 0):

MSCB internally encapsulates a Checkboxlist. Try something like (Flex 3):

CheckBoxList
   {

```
            backgroundAlpha: 0.9;
             backgroundColor: #EFEFEF;
             color: #444444;



}
```

Or

controls|CheckBoxList
{

```
        backgroundAlpha: 0.9;
        backgroundColor: #EFEFEF;
        color: #444444;
```

}